# 18.04 Dash to Dock random additional scaled dock appears on top of regular dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool, dash-to-dock

In Ubuntu 18.04 w/ GNOME 3.28, I just tried the [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension and it works great,  but sometimes an additional scaled dock [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lul4p.png) appears on top of the regular dock, when I enter the app menu.

How might I troubleshoot this to prevent the additional scaled dock from appearing?